# How can I specify the contents of a multidimensional array and select objects matching the criteria from a list?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

#### Premise

We are creating a tower defense type game. So we want to build a Wave system and be able to set the number of Wave times each enemy will spring up according to their respective types.

- Select the type of enemy to be generated from `EnemyFactor`
- Select the number of enemies to be generated from `EnemyAmount`

[image]

#### What you want to achieve

- Select enemy type from list and game object

#### Applicable source code

```
    public class WaveListFactor : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public List<EnemyEnum> enemyFactor = new List<EnemyEnum>();

        public List<int> enemyAmount = new List<int>();
    }
```

```
    public class WaveList : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public List<GameObject> enemyList = new List<GameObject>();

        public List<WaveListFactor> waveEnemies = new List<WaveListFactor>();
    }
```

```
    public class WaveManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public void EnemySpawn()
        {
            int enemyFactor = waveList.waveEnemies.waveEnemyFactor;
            GameObject enemy = waveList.enemyList[enemyFactor];
            waveSpawner.Spawn(enemy);
        }
    }
```

#### Problems

```
int enemyFactor = waveList.waveEnemies.waveEnemyFactor;
```

Now I can't change `EnemyEnum` in `EnemyFactor` to `int` and can't specify the contents of `enemyList`.

#### Supplementary information (FW / tool version, etc.)

- Unity 2020.3.20f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you rather use a [`SerializedDictionary<EnemyEnum, GameObject[]>`](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/serializabledictionary-90477) and simply configure beforehand which enum value results in which `GameObject` prefab options (so you can still randomize a bit)

```
public SerializedDictionary<EnemyEnum, GameObject[]> enemyList = new SerializedDictionary<EnemyEnum, GameObject[]>();
```

and then later select one doing

```
var options = enemyList[enemyFactor];
```

and then select a random one like e.g.

```
var selectedPrefab = options[Random.Range(0, options.Length)];
```

---

Otherwise you would need some dedicated component on your enemies that provides the information about which `EnemyEnum` it responds to like e.g.

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public EnymeEnum Type;
}
```

and rather have

```
public List<Enemy> enemyList = new List<Enemy>();
```

then you could filter your available options using `Linq`

```
using System.Linq;

...

var options = enemyList.Where(enemy => enemy.Type == enemyFactor).ToArray();
```

and pick a random one from the existing matches like

```
var selectedPrefab = options[Random.Range(0, options.Length)];
```

if this results in `null` it simply means there is no matching prefab.

**Disadvantage**: Each prefab can only belong to one single enum category. That's not the case for the other two solutions.

---

Or even simplier: Why store the information in separate collections at all?

Simply rather have a

```
[Seriaizable]
public class EnemyInfo
{
    public GameObject Prefab;
    public int Amount;
}

[Seriaizable]
public class WaveInfo
{
    public EnemyInfo[] EnemyInfos;
}
```

this way you don't have to care about any enum but rather simply define how many instances of which prefab will be spawned.